# Who are the philosophical successors of Kuhn?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy

That improved and extended his concepts in the 'Structure of the scientific revolution'.

Comment: No one; Kuhn was not a philosopher, but an historian of science.

Comment: But his work is inbued with philosophy of science and philosophy of history of science

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA [SEP disagrees](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thomas-kuhn/):"*Kuhn is one of the most influential philosophers of science of the twentieth century, perhaps the most influential*". As for "successors", it depends on what that means. Much of post-Kuhnian philosophy of science had to *respond* to Kuhn. [Scientific structuralism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physics-structuralism/), especially Sneed, built on some of his ideas, [sociology of scientific knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology_of_scientific_knowledge) developed others.